# Rails not detecting in windows 10 command prompt

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I tried `rails -v` but I am getting

> 'rails' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable
>   program or batch file.

I have done `gem install rails --no-document` and it installed `Rails 5.0.1` but `rails -v` not working

I have set the environment variable to `C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.3.0\bin\rails.bat`

I have followed this guide http://installfest.railsbridge.org/installfest/windows

Thanks.

Comment: can you confirm that you have ruby installed correctly by running ruby -v

Comment: Yes it's showing ruby version 2.4

Comment: Try changing the env variable to just C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.3.0\bin

Comment: Env was set to that and it didn't work so I added rails.bat to it.

Comment: I never tried installing rails with that railsinstaller. Perhaps start again but install ruby from scratch. Also don't forget the Dev tools. Then set environment variable to the ruby bin folder and try installing rails again

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, `PATHEXT` is missing .BAT from it. This is the environment variable responsible for knowing files to be executed without extensions .

To confirm, please do `SET PATHEXT` on a new command prompt and see the output, the result should be a semi-colon separated values that include .EXE, .BAT, .COM and perhaps .RB

If PATHEXT is empty or do not contain .BAT in it, that could explain why is not working.

This usually happens when windows versions do not match with that of rails. To solve, uninstall RubyInstaller and reboot the system and verify. I f variables are not restored, reinstall ruby. this should fix your problem.

Source: Ruby Documentations

Comment: I went and added rails.bat myself in the environment variable after installing it but still it's not working.

Comment: I suggest completely flushing and uninstalling current versions. Also install ruby and corresponding components individually. You can check official rails guides and debugging here.guides.rubyonrails.org

Comment: Also do not forget to reboot every time after uninstalling and reinstalling. This helps cleanup temporary files in buffer.